# Nginx: Point Sub Domain to Main Domain but keep the URL

Tags: nginx

Here is my situation in a nginx web server:

I have: domain.com and sub.domain.com

I need subdomain.com serving the same content (same files) of domain.com but keeping the url (sub.domain.com) - Not redirect.

I have this setting in sub.domain.com.conf:

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name  sub.domain.com;
root         /home/domain.com/public_html;
```

But when I access sub.domain.com it showed 404 Not Found.

But would like to hear your thoughts on this... Thanks

Comment: You are using SSL, do you have both `domain.com` and `sub.domain.com` listed under SAN (Subject Alternative Name) field of your SSL certificate or you are using two different certificates?

Comment: @IvanShatsky I'm using the same certificate for both, domain.com and sub.domain.com.

Comment: Then the only thing you need is to add your subdomain to the `server_name` directive: `server_name domain.com sub.domain.com;`. You don't need two separate `server` blocks at all.